# Sending an email to multiple recipients in Alfresco

Tags: javascript, email, alfresco

The Alfresco documentation [talks about a paramater `to_many`](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Outbound_E-mail_Configuration#Email_Action_Executor) to send an email to multiple recipients. Using this parameter from JavaScript does not work for me.

```
mail.parameters.to = "User 0 <user0@example.com>";
mail.parameters.to_many = "User 1 <user1@example.com>, User 2 <user2@example.com>";
```

Using *both* `to` and `to_many` like this ignores `to_many` and only send to `to`.

Using *only* `to_many` like

```
mail.parameters.to_many = "User 1 <user1@example.com>, User 2 <user2@example.com>";
```

throws a NPE at

```
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:557)
```

What is the correct way to use `to_many` in JavaScript to send an email to multiple recipients?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The parameter `to_many` is expected to be an array of authority names.

```
mail.parameters.to_many = ['username1', 'GROUP_ALFRESCO_ADMINISTRATORS'];
```

Will send the email to the user with username1 and  all members of the ALFRESCO_ADMINISTRATORS group.

Comment: Thanks, that's how it is done. I wonder that it is not possible to pass an array of formated mail addresses like `["User 1 <user1@example.com>", ...]`. This is possible for `to = "User 1 <user1@example.com>"`.

Comment: I guess it's just like that because allowing an array of email addresses would require introducing another parameter as you cannot easily tell whether a String is meant to be an email or an authority.

Comment: Yes, that is probably true. My expectation was that both `to` and `to_many` accept preformated `To` header lines. As it is implemented now, I can not send an emails to recipients that are not authorities in Alfresco. That's not a problem for my current project but I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Alfresco v.5.2 EA9 supports mixed array of email address, users and groups:

```
 mail.parameters.to_many = [
     'user0@example.com',
     '"User 1" <user1@example.com>', 
     'username1', 
     'GROUP_ALFRESCO_ADMINISTRATORS'];
```

You can use https://papercut.codeplex.com/ to test it, Alfresco configuration:

```
# smtp settings
mail.host=localhost
mail.port=25
mail.protocol=smtp
mail.smtp.auth=false
# mail.smtp.timeout=30000
# mail.smtp.debug=true
```